# OpenCV - in OSX is failing to capture the camera

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, camera

Why in OSX my code is not showing any camera capture at all?

[image]

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main() {
  VideoCapture stream1(0);   //0 or 1 or 2 same..

  if (!stream1.isOpened()) {
    cout << "cannot open camera";
  }


  while (true) {
    Mat cameraFrame;
    stream1.read(cameraFrame);
    imshow("cam", cameraFrame);
    if (waitKey(30) >= 0)
      break;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Solved]** Problem was solved by replacing the value

`VideoCapture stream1(2);`